# Create wider selection area to select lines on map using LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet, line, select, leaflet-draw, leaflet-plugins

When there are thin lines on the map, it is very difficult to click them with the mouse cursor. So is there any option to wider the selection area for lines in LeafletJS, without increasing the line width.

Here is the example code:

```
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script>
  const map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

  const tiles = L.tileLayer(
    "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    }
  ).addTo(map);

  var latlngs = [
    [45.51, -122.68],
    [37.77, -122.43],
    [34.04, -118.2],
  ];

  const polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, { color: "red" }).addTo(map);

  map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
  polyline.bindPopup("I am a polyline");
</script>
```

The default weight of line is 3 and it should remain unchanged.

Comment: Here, I don't want to increase the line width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create wider selection area when selecting lines on Leaflet map you can use `L.canvas` map renderer with the `tolerance` option (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#canvas).

To extend click tolerance for all paths on the map by 2 pixels, code could then look like this:

```
const canvasRenderer = L.canvas({
  tolerance: 2
});
  
const map = L.map("map", {
  renderer: canvasRenderer
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Instead for the whole map, you can specify wider click tolerance only for individual vector layer:

```
const polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {
  renderer: canvasRenderer,
  color: "red"
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

Clicking on lines, or show tooltips is a common issue in leaflet. The first solution is increase the tolerance as explained in other answer.

Usually I prefer to fix it with the plugin [Leaflet.AlmostOver](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.AlmostOver). When writing this is not updated from 2019, but it is still working on Leaflet v1.9.4.

The README is a bit incomplete, check the main options [directly in the code](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.AlmostOver/blob/gh-pages/src/leaflet.almostover.js#L1). I extract the main bits here:

```js
L.Map.mergeOptions({
    // @option almostOver: Boolean = true
    // Set it to false to disable this plugin
    almostOver: true,
    // @option almostDistance: Number = 25
    // Tolerance in pixels
    almostDistance: 25,   // pixels
    // @option almostSamplingPeriod: Number = 50
    // To reduce the 'mousemove' event frequency. In milliseconds
    almostSamplingPeriod: 50,  // ms
    // @option almostOnMouseMove Boolean = true
    // Set it to false to disable track 'mousemove' events and improve performance
    // if AlmostOver is only need for 'click' events.
    almostOnMouseMove: true,
});`
```

If the layer has many features it can be slow, so disable following mouse move if hover is not needed. And commonly adjust the tolerance (in px):

```js
const map = L.map('map', {
    almostOnMouseMove: false,
    almostDistance: 20, 
});

# being `lines` a geojson line layer
map.almostOver.addLayer(lines);

map.on('almost:click', function (e) {
    alert('Almost clicked !');
});
```

Comment: There seems to be no way to adjust "almost" tolerance with this plugin.

Comment: I updated my answer, is possible done it, but the README that not includes that info.

Comment: Earlier I tried the solution of @TomazicM but the renderer property was not working and I had posted that here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098650/renderer-is-not-working-in-pathoptions-for-the-polyline-in-react-leaflet

Comment: @Kishor I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/9qk0vfy3/. When you draw a line, it has select/click tolerance of 10 pixels.

Comment: @TomazicM The solution you provided is working fine. But I tried to implement the same with `react-leaflet` `PolyLine` which I have posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098650/renderer-is-not-working-in-pathoptions-for-the-polyline-in-react-leaflet

Comment: @Kishor You didn't mention React in your question.

Comment: @TomazicM, I apologies for it., I thought the same solution can be implemented in react  also, So I didn't mentioned it. 
Now can I implement the same with `react-leaflet` `Polyline`.